# The data in the time series is different from the data I entered. How do I get outputs in a similar scale as my inputs?

Tags: r, time-series, data-analysis

I had a column of data as follows:

```
141523
146785
143667
65560
88524
148422
151664
```

.
.
.
.

I used the ts() function to convert this data into a time series.

```
{ 

Aclines <- read.csv(file.choose())

Aclinests <- ts(Aclines[[1]], start = c(2013), end = c(2015), frequency = 52)

}
```

head(Aclines) gives me the following output:

```
  X141.523
1  146785
2  143667
3   65560
4   88524
5  148422
6  151664
```

head(Aclinests) gives me the following output:

```
 [1] 26 16 83 87 35 54
```

The output of all my further analysis including graphs and predictions are scaled to how you can see the head(Aclinets) output. How can I scale the outputs back to how the original data was input? Am I missing something while converting the data to a ts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is typically recommended to have a reproducible example [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  But I will try to help based what I'm reading.  If it isn't helpful, I'll delete the post.

First, the `read.csv` defaults to `header = TRUE`.  It doesn't look like you have a header in your file.  Also, it looks like R is reading data in as factors instead of numeric.

So you can try a couple of parameters to reading the file -

```
Aclines <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then to get your time series

```
Aclinests <- ts(Aclines[, 2], start = c(2013), end = c(2015), frequency = 52)
```

Since your data looks like it has 2 columns, this will read the second column of your data frame into a `ts` object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am new to R and stackoverflow and I will keep what you told me in mind about reproducible examples. Your answer helped me partially. I now get my input values of the original data in my time-series as well. However, when I use the 'plot' function I get an error which I have asked using a reproducible example in this question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340002/error-while-creating-a-timeseries-plot-in-r-error-in-plot-windowxlim-ylim-lo>

Please let me know if you can have a look.